# Generating a list of all possible combinations of true or false for n given variables in LISP

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I want to define a function that takes an input "n" (the number of variables) and return all possible truth values. Here, I represent the truth values for a variable i (1 <= i <= n) with +i representing true, and -i representing false.

For example:

```
(generate-values 2)
```

should return:

```
((2 1)(2 -1)(-2 1)(-2 -1))

(generate-values 3)
```

should return:

```
((3 2 1)(3 2 -1)(3 -2 1)(3 -2 -1)(-3 2 1)(-3 2 -1)(-3 -2 1)(-3 -2 -1))
```

Here is my incorrect attempt:

```
(defun generate-values (n)
  (cond
   ((equal n 0) nil)
   (t (list (cons n (generate-values (- n 1)))
            (cons (- 0 n) (generate-values (- n 1)))))))
```

I know why this is incorrect, but I am not able to find a way to generate `(3 2 1)` and then move on to `(3 2 -1)`. My program outputs:

```
 ((3 (2 (1) (-1)) (-2 (1) (-1))) (-3 (2 (1) (-1)) (-2 (1) (-1))))
```

Any help with this question qould be thoroughly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easiest to approach this in the easiest way possible, and then to figure out how to make it a bit simpler or more efficient afterward.

If you're doing this recursively, it's important to consider what the bases cases are.  A reasonable base case here is probably when **n = 0**.  The function is always supposed to return a *list of lists*.  In the **n = 0** case, there are no "variables", so the result has to be a list of the empty list: **(())**.

For the case that **n** is anything else, consider what the function returns for **n-1**.  It's a list of all the combinations on **n-1** "variables".  All you need to do is prepend **n** to each of those, and prepend **-n** to each of those, and then make sure you end up with a list of all of those.

Encoding that directly, we end up with something like this:

```
(defun table (n)
  (if (zerop n)
      '(())
      (let* ((table (table (1- n)))
             (plus-pos-n (mapcar (lambda (subtable)
                                   (list* n subtable))
                                 table))
             (plus-neg-n (mapcar (lambda (subtable)
                                   (list* (- n) subtable))
                                 table)))
        (nconc plus-pos-n plus-neg-n))))
```

```
CL-USER> (table 3)
((3 2 1) (3 2 -1) (3 -2 1) (3 -2 -1) (-3 2 1) (-3 2 -1) (-3 -2 1) (-3 -2 -1))
```

Now, let's look at what your current implementation is doing differently, noting that it doesn't *have* to be exactly the same algorithm, of course.

```
(defun generate-values (n)
  (cond
    ((equal n 0)
     nil)
    (t
     (list (cons n
                   (generate-values (- n 1)))
             (cons (- 0 n)
                   (generate-values (- n 1)))))))
```

Stylistically, since there are only two branches, I'd prefer **if** to **cond** here, but that's not a problem.  Before attacking the base case, lets look at the recursive case, when **n ≠ 0**.  First, you're calling **generate-values** twice;  it would be more efficient to call it once and save the result.  That could end up being important later if you're calling this function with big values of **n**, but it doesn't make the function incorrect.  But remember what **generate-values** returns;  it returns a list of the different combinations.  That means that your call to **(cons n (generate-values …))** is returning a list whose first element is **n**, and whose remaining elements are the combinations for **n-1**.  E.g., you're doing something like:

```
CL-USER> (table 1)
((1) (-1))
CL-USER> (cons 2 (table 1))
(2 (1) (-1))
```

But that's not what you want.  You really want to add **n** to each of those lists:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar (lambda (x)
                   (cons 2 x))
                 (table 1))
((2 1) (2 -1))
```

That's the issue in the recursive case.  There's an issue in the base case, too.  In the recursive case, you want to add **n** and **-n** to each of the sublists from the **n-1** case.  So what happens when you have **n = 1**?  You want to be getting **(cons 1 '())** and **(cons -1 '())**.  But since the second argument to **cons** is going to be each list inside of the result of **(generate-values 0)**, you *really* need to have something *in* the list returned by **(generate-values 0)**.  What needs to be there?  The empty list needs to be there.  So the base case needs to return **(())**, not **()**.  So, after making those changes, your code would be:

```
(defun generate-values (n)
  (cond
    ((equal n 0)
     '(()))
    (t
     (list (mapcar (lambda (x)
                     (cons n x))
                   (generate-values (- n 1)))
           (mapcar (lambda (x)
                     (cons (- 0 n) x))
                   (generate-values (- n 1)))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (generate-values 3)
(((3 (2 (1)) (2 (-1))) (3 (-2 (1)) (-2 (-1))))
 ((-3 (2 (1)) (2 (-1))) (-3 (-2 (1)) (-2 (-1)))))
```

That's closer, but it's still not quite right.  There's another in the recursive case.  You end up generating the values that have **n** in the beginning (a list of them), and the values that have **-n** in the beginning (a list of them), but then you're using **list** to combine them.  That returns a single list with two values.  Instead, you want a single list that has the values from each of them.  You want to combine them with **append** (or, since all the structure is newly generated, you could use **nconc**):

```
(defun generate-values (n)
  (cond
    ((equal n 0)
     '(()))
    (t
     (append (mapcar (lambda (x)
                       (cons n x))
                     (generate-values (- n 1)))
             (mapcar (lambda (x)
                       (cons (- 0 n) x))
                     (generate-values (- n 1)))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (generate-values 3)
((3 2 1) (3 2 -1) (3 -2 1) (3 -2 -1) (-3 2 1) (-3 2 -1) (-3 -2 1) (-3 -2 -1))
```

This final implementation isn't exactly what I started with, but it's essentially the same in terms of the algorithm.  The differences are mostly stylistic, but there are some efficiency concerns, too.  Using **nconc** instead of **append** would save some memory, and it really would be good to cache the results from the recursive call, rather than recomputing it.  Stylistic issues that don't affect correctness might be using **if** instead of **cond**, using **list*** instead of **cons** (to indicate that we're working with lists, not trees of cons cells), and it's nice to note that you don't have to do **(- 0 n)**, **-** with a single argument returns the argument's negation.  That is, **(- n) = -n**.